# ¿Se puede instalar WORDPRESS en Apache Tomcat?

Tags: wordpress, tomcat

tengo una pagina web actual en un servidor local montado en apache tomcat 6.0.20.

Lo que busco es instalar wordpress en este apache, pero no puedo lograrlo por problemas de compatibilidad.

Alguien ya paso por este problema o sabe de alguna solucion?

Comment: Y por qué en Tomcat? Necesitas un contenedor web de servlets (Java) para ofrecer un Wordpress? Además, ese Tomcat ya no es soportado, es viejo y tiene muchas vulnerabilidades expuestas.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en ese tomcat tengo varias API's con la misma URL que quiero que tenga mi pagina web. Y esas API's estan en distintas aplicaciones y servicios web de terceros, y seria bastante complicado contactarme con estos terceros y decirles que cambien la URL de las API's.

Comment: Es falso creer que necesitas todo en el mismo servidor para que esté expuesto con la misma URL. Pones un haproxy/nginx delante del tomcat y de lo que elijas para servir el wordpress y ya está, todo por la misma URL y tú defines las reglas de enrutamiento. Y depordiós, actualiza ese Tomcat!

Comment: Ok, a ver si entendí, con un haproxy/nginx puedo hacer que las peticiones de las API's vayan por el servidor tomcat y por otro lado se acceda a la pagina en wordpress aunque este alojado en otro hosting? Es esto asi?

Comment: Pues _en teoría_ sí. Sin hacks que corran PHP en Tomcat. Ya si hay más locuras como poner wordpress por allá en un hosting de godaddy, se enreda. Idealmente, esa configuración va bien si el tomcat y, digamos, el apache http sirven sus contenidos estando en el mismo servidor / misma red / mismo entorno y con eso controlas que realmente el punto de ingreso sea el balanceador. Como ves, tu pregunta de fondo es otra y es más amplia :)

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por tu información... yyyy si, ya es hora de actualizar ese tomcat 6 jajaja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como respuesta formal a tu pregunta, es posible usar un bridge que permita a Tomcat usar PHP y servir tu sitio web.

Hay varias opciones:

- instalar PHP en el servidor, obtener la versión más reciente de [php-java-bridge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/Binary%20package/) (última actualización en 2018) y configurarlo todo (como lo indican [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51665443/236345)).
- Usar PECL para extender PHP y añadir la extensión php_java. Como problema, esta probado para PHP 5 y Wordpress puede que exija una versión más reciente. (tomado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840625/236345)).
- Guiarse por [documentación de Apache](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tomcat/UsingPhp), pero es para versiones muy viejas.
- Tal vez la más viable, usar Quercus, que entiendo que es una implementación de PHP (creo que PHP5) en Java. [Esta guía](https://www.studytrails.com/2014/07/02/php-on-a-java-app-server-apache-tomcat-using-quercus/) explica qué hacer, que básicamente es:

  - Instalar Tomcat
  - Descargar Quercus y descomprimir el WAR en /webapps/
  - Arrancar el Tomcat
  - Probar, usando la raíz de Tomcat como raíz de tu servicio. (No sé eso cómo afecte el acceso a tus APIs en webapps...)

En general, la recomendación para evitar tantísimos hacks y vueltas, es que Tomcat se encargue de lo que le corresponde, los servlets, y que alguien más sirva el contenido PHP. Dos nodos (dos servicios en el mismo servidor o en servidores diferentes, como prefieras). Apache HTTP o Nginx o muchos otros son muy buenos. Frente a ellos, un proxy reverso puede definir qué rutas van a tomcat y qué rutas van a donde esté wordpress.